# Installing git to be used in a multi-user system

Tags: ssh, users, git, gitosis

I need to install git on a server that will be shared and accessed by multiple users.

I assume I will use git+ssh, so each user will have a system account, but how do I go about install git and a repository so that each user can push/pull over a local IP?

Answer (score 2):

[gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) may make things easier for you.

Comment: Gitosis is the only worth-time solution right now... however it needs a second look. +1 ;)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Gitosis is described in the Ubuntu Wiki:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git#Setting%20up%20Git%20and%20Project%20Management

Gitosis is a widely used git server. The advantage with it is, that the settings are a git repository. After the initial setup, you can just change settings, push them and they'll automatically be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you just need to set each user's umask to 0002, add create various groups for them to work together in (e.g. `sudo addgroup some-project; sudo adduser USER some-project`) and create a directory for them to collaborate in (e.g. `sudo mkdir -p /srv/git/some-project`) and then make the directory writable (and setgid) for the group (e.g. `sudo chown root:coders /srv/git/some-project; sudo chmod g+ws /srv/git/some-project`)